# iOS hot questions widget freezes after app crash

Tags: bug, status-norepro, ios-app, ios-app-today-view

My 'hot questions' widget has just frozen for the 3rd time. By this I mean, it can't be tapped, doesn't load any new questions, and doesn't resize properly if the question text is >2 lines. I only seem to be able to clear it by restarting my phone.

[image]

I'm not *entirely* sure of the cause, but I know at least the last 2 times its frozen, it's been after the apps recently crashed. (Once on a bug now foxed, and once on loading a big question, which I presume was out of memory - I may post the details of that one tomorrow!) I also thought that would be pretty easy to test, for someone who can make the app crash!

I currently have it in its frozen state, so could send logs in it there's likely to be anything helpful. iPhone 4s, iOS 8.1.3, app v1.2.2.18X-193

Comment: Just come across the iOS-app-today-view tag. That's surely not the right name for it...is it?!?

Comment: I've not been able to reproduce this.  I'm guessing it was an iOS bug.