# Add reputation iOS widget

Tags: feature-request, ios-app, ios-app-today-view

I loved having my Stack Overflow rep on my home screen in Android. I've moved on to iPhone and I wish there was a widget for reputation.

Is anyone active on the app? This would be a great feature. Much more of my style than Hot Questions.

Comment: Does iOS even allow for widgets?

Comment: @AlE. yep http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/250035/ios-hot-questions-widget-freezes-after-app-crash

Comment: How to determine the site to show the reputation for?

Comment: @PatrickHofman i've seen apps ask in some setting area.